# Credits as Currency

Tags: magento-1.7, currency

I want to setup my magento community 1.7 store with a "credits system" for payments. 
The target is that the clients can buy packages of credits and thereafter, buy products. The products price should also be displayed in credit units and not in standard currency format ($, €, etc).

Found some extensions but none would do the deal exactly like this.

Comment: Just a crazy idea. How about using any currency (let's say Euro or USD) and just change the way the currency is displayed in the frontend? From System->Manage Currency->Symbols.

Comment: @Marius: Great idea - IMHO

Comment: That can work for the price display but I would still need a system that could manage credit units. I mean, the client should be able to buy "50 credits" and this credits should be stored on client's account for present and future use.

Comment: That can be done also. You can sell virtual products (just like discount vouchers). There are extensions for that. I've used this before and it does the job. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-giftcert.html. It allows you to sell vouchers in a specific currency, but since you replace Euro with 'Points' it should be the same thing.

Comment: Be careful of Giftcert, there are some versions of it with Malware that grab credit card numbers. Crazy idea - guess technies aren't really interested in fraud prevention. It's a great idea but you need to take in to account multi-currency, currency purchase, etc. It is included in EE - Store Credit - so you might want to use that as a basis for searching extensions. Try separating the two requirements first.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments.
You can just use any currency and replace the currency symbol with 'points' from `System->Manage Currency->Symbols`.
If you want to use coupons, you can use an extension.
I recommend [this one](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-giftcert.html) but you can choose your own.
Or you can create a virtual product that costs `50 points`. Then, when an order is made and paid, you can create a discount rule manually for those points. The downside of this is that you have to process each order manually.

The advantage of this approach (changing only currency symbol) is that you will be able to use online payment methods without having to interfere with the process.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not solve my problem. What I need is a credit system manager, where users can buy several credits and store them on their account for shopping over time, not an isolated transaction using credits. The way shutterstock works is a good example of what i'm looking for.

Comment: I think the extension I recommended can do this, but not entirely sure. Well...sorry, that's the best I could come up with.